# SQLAlchemy alphabetical ordering query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to order the rows returned by a SQLAlchemy query alphabetically in the actual query, or is the only way to order alphabetically is to sort the list of rows that the query returns.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add an `order_by` clause:

```
query = query.order_by(MyTable.column_name)
```

Comment: So by just specifying the column name its default is alphabetical?

Comment: @Wiz: By default, it is default sorting. If it is `char`-based, it will be alphabetical. If the column is numerical, it will be numeric sorting. IN this case you can cast it to char-based: `cast(MyTable.column_name, VARCHAR(255))`.